# How to use RadioButtonList to show/hide div

Tags: asp.net

I have RadioButtonList with 3 option :

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="SearchByName" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="SearchByDate" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="SearchByValue" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

and I have 3 divs each one have some textboxes and button to make some search.
How can I use radiobuttonlist and when i check some radio only one div shows

Comment: Using jquery is an option

Comment: u wana do with java script or with code behind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two approaches to this, you can either do it in the client side, or you can do it on the server side, depending on your needs:

**Server Side Solution**: You need to add the `AutoPostBack` property of your RadioButtonList to true, and the `divs` will have the `runat` property set to `server`

**Markup**:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="SearchByName" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="SearchByDate" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="SearchByValue" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<div id="myDiv1" runat="server" visible="false">Div Content</div>
```

**Code behind**:

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue =="2")
                this.myDiv1.Visible = true;
    else
        this.myDiv1.Visible = false;

}
```

**Client Side Solution**:

**Javascript**:

```
 window.onload = function () {
            var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

            if (inputs.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    if (inputs[i].type == "radio") {
                        inputs[i].onclick = function () {
                            if (this.value == "2") {
                                document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block";
                            }
                            else {
                                document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Markup**:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="SearchByName" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="SearchByDate" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="SearchByValue" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<div id="div1" style="display:none">Div Content</div>
```

Of course this will get all of the radio buttons in the page, so you may want to make sure that you got the right ones.

Comment: You should see div if you set runat="server" and assigned an id to it.

Answer (score 6):

**Better you use Client Side Script for this type of Actions**...

I have written the below code using JQuery try that...

**JQuery :**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#RadioButtonList1 input').click(function () {
                var value = $('#RadioButtonList1 input:checked').val();
                if (value == 1) {
                    $("#divName").show();
                    $("#divDate").hide();
                    $("#divValue").hide();
                }
                if (value == 2) {
                    $("#divName").hide();
                    $("#divDate").show();
                    $("#divValue").hide();
                }
                if (value == 3) {
                    $("#divName").hide();
                    $("#divDate").hide();
                    $("#divValue").show();
                }

            });
        });
</script>
```

**HTML :**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="SearchByName" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="SearchByDate" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="SearchByValue" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<div id="divName">Search By Name</div>
<div id="divDate">Search By Date</div>
<div id="divValue">Search By Value</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the `AutoPostback = "true"`, handle the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event and then show/hide the appropriate div in code behind. Something like this:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList AutoPostBack="True"  
 OnSelectedIndexChanged="Index_Changed" ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="SearchByName" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="SearchByDate" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="SearchByValue" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>


protected void Index_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

   if(RadioButtonList1.SelectedIte.Value=="1")
   {
      div1.Visible=true;
      div2.Visible=false;
      div3.Visible=false;
   else if(RadioButtonList1.SelectedIte.Value=="2")
   {
      div2.Visible=true;
      //and so on...
   }
}
```

Obviously, the divs themselves, must be server-side controls, so you must declared them like so:

```
<div id="div1" runat="server">
content here
</div>
```